# How can I reassign the tab function to the tab button?

Tags: eclipse

I changed the functionality of my tab button, now the <kbd>Tab</kbd>  key auto-completes instead of adding 5 spaces.

I want to re-assign the tab key to adding a tab(spaces) in my code instead of auto-completing.

I removed the <kbd>Tab</kbd> from the auto-completion function, but now my tab button does nothing, how do I add the default tab?

Comment: How did you change it the first time? And this is **not** how you set tabs to create spaces, in Eclipse that's usually a Preference for the editor you're using.

Comment: Well, I went to the auto complete functionality and changed the key for it to tab, now my tab button auto completes, but it does not add tabs.